# Styling Android view - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I've got a small question about styling an android application in Xamarin Studio.
I want to style my application like the design in the picture.
[image: appdesign]
**Sorry for the size of the picture.**

Can someone tell me how i can style a view.

I have looked far and wide to find an awnser to my question. If i would build this in visual studio i woul use panels. I've searched for andoird app apppearence but then i get the appearence api for IOS.

Please if you know a way please say so

I want to be very clear about this, i do not want you to think i am asking for code. I am asking for a way to style my application to look like this picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on Android Styles and Themes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

This should get you started.